# When using Azure AppFabric Cache as a Session State Provider what causes a transaction

Tags: session, azure, appfabric, azure-caching, azure-appfabric

I have AppFabric Cache configured as the Session State Provider for an ASP.NET MVC application. Not all pages access session state (in fact only a few ajax requests do, the main pages commonly accessed by the site users don't, in order to make them cacheable) Give the hourly transaction limit on AppFabric cache, what causes the Session Provider to execute a transaction with the Cache ? (See @knightpfhor answer on [Estimating simultaneous Azure Appfabric Cache Connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964228/estimating-simultaneous-azure-appfabric-cache-connections)  for the source of this query)

Is it

1. any resource (inc images / css)
2. any request/page executing code
3. any request/page with an explicit Session reference
4. something else?

Comment: I don't want to be concrete, but my guess is that a Cache transaction will only be executed when an object is added to, or retrieved from the Cache. I'm not sure whether the Session_Start would also generate a transaction, but even if it does, it is still very rare comparing to every page/resource request.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. They align with my guesses too: just need someone who knows :-)

Comment: What I got for sure is that you have 1 connection per role instance. However I could not get a concrete answer for the transactions.